# View scripts ran by a specific user?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recovery, plan-cache

I read [in a stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034832/recover-unsaved-sql-query-scripts-sql-server) that you can restore scripts from the past 24 hours by using this query:

```
Use <database>
SELECT execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time], execsql.text AS [Script] FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC
```

But I want to see only queries which a specific user ran, how can I perform this?

Comment: That query shows you the text of queries that happen to be in the plan cache. It is absolutely **not** an exhaustive list of all SQL that was executed in the past 24 hours.

Answer (score 4):

In order to achieve it, you'll need to capture this information at run time using DMV's or Extended Events.

Answer (score 2):

Below query will help you :

```
SELECT cr.DatabaseName
    ,s.session_id
    ,s.host_name
    ,s.program_name
    ,s.client_interface_name
    ,s.login_name
    ,s.login_time
    ,s.nt_domain
    ,s.nt_user_name
    ,c.client_net_address
    ,c.local_net_address
    ,cr.ObjName
    ,cr.Query
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS c ON c.session_id = s.session_id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT db_name(dbid) AS DatabaseName
        ,object_id(objectid) AS ObjName
        ,ISNULL((
                SELECT TEXT AS [processing-instruction(definition)]
                FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle)
                FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,TYPE
                ), '') AS Query

    FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle)
    ) cr
where s.nt_user_name = '' -- filter here your user name
and s.session_id <> @@SPID
ORDER BY c.session_id
```

Comment: This query would work alright if the connection still exists. If it was closed, not so much, unfortunately.

Comment: @Marian Agreed. The other way is ONLY auditing through profiler (server side trace) or XEvents.